# Datetime field using military time - need time only in standard time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a datetime field in SQL Server 2008 which stores the date and time in military format (or international format if you prefer)

examples:

```
2011-02-15 10:00:00.000
2011-02-15 15:30:00.000
2011-02-15 17:30:00.000
```

I need to retrieve the time only portion of this in standard U.S. time format.

So

```
2011-02-15 10:00:00.000    needs to become 10:00 AM
2011-02-15 15:30:00.000    needs to become 3:30 PM
2011-02-15 17:30:00.000    needs to become 5:30 PM
```

I am looking for the best way to accomplish this in T-SQL please.

Comment: "Military time" is a misnomer - it's the standard in the vast majority of countries worldwide - so **THAT** should be called the standard, really...

Comment: @marc_s - And yet, that's not how they are stored in SQL Server...

Comment: @JamieF: yes, of course - you're absolutely right!

Comment: Whatever you prefer to call military time or international time is fine with me.  I am simply looking for an effective and efficient way to take the datetime field and retrieve the timeonly portion in U.S. format.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way is:

Convert to varchar, which will give you:

```
Select CONVERT(varchar, @dt, 100) -- where @dt is your date time
```

Feb 15 2011  3:30PM

Subsequently, to remove the date, and get 7 chars from the right, which is the most, and TRIM is added just for extra safety, but probably isn't needed.

```
Select LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, @dt, 100),7))
```

Will give you 3:30PM

Side Note: [Denali](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/ana/archive/2011/09/02/sql-server-denali-format-string-function.aspx) makes this easier, no more magic numbers

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is stored in an internal representation - there is no format associated. When you need to display the DateTime, specify the formatting you want for converting the DateTime into a string.

It is *much* better to let the application decide on formatting than formatting in SQL.

See [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) Date and Time Format Strings for more information.

Comment: Yes I understand. I am looking for efficient code to convert the date time to time only in u.s format in t-sql.

Comment: @Matt - You really should be doing that in the application.

Comment: I would love to. But this is for a programmatic mail merge into a word document in which sql server returns the fields directly into the mail  mail merge field in an enterprise level application. Over 200 forms are running in this manner and no front end code is availabe in this situation.

Comment: @Matt - You can't format the returned date during mail merge?

Comment: Not an option in this case  unfortunately. Formatting up front would be a piece of cake. But unfortunately I need a t-sql solution to this. I am working on an enterprise level app that has a mail merge factory in place in which all mail merge fields map directly to sql server fields and there is never any front end code.

Answer (score 1):

As you requested this in T-SQL, you might want to look at the [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) syntax which specifically lists various date and time formats.

For example:

`select convert(varchar, getdate(), 100)`

Would give you:

`Feb  3 2012  3:26PM`

Comment: Yes I have looked at this and am not finding a solution thus far.

Comment: As Oded has said, this should be done in app code, but as you've stated that isn't possible, I think that string manipulation is your only hope (as per kd7's answer).