# How to show military hours for the last 48 hours?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to show military hours with `30` minute interval for the last `48` hours and also show the date.

For instance:

```
Military_Hour        Date
0000              2015-02-17             
0030              2015-02-17
0100              2015-02-17
0130              2015-02-17
.                 .
.                 .
2330              2015-02-17

0000              2015-02-16            
0030              2015-02-16
0100              2015-02-16
0130              2015-02-16
.                 .
.                 .
2330              2015-02-16
```

Comment: What error are you getting?    Can you show your code attempt?

Comment: As a rule formatting is best left to your application, not something to be done in the database without a good reason.

Comment: Do you have actual data for each interval or are you needing to synthesize the intervals even if there's no corresponding data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to create the blocks from nothing then use this query. If you're want to round/truncate data in a table to 30-minute blocks then that's a different question.

```
declare @baseDate date = '20150216';
select
    /* SQL Server 2012 and later */
    --format(timeBlock, 'HHmm') as Military_Hour,
    --format(timeBlock, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as "Date",
    /* or earlier versions */
    timeBlock,
    convert(char(10), timeBlock, 120) as "Date", /* one of many options */
    cast(stuff(
        substring(convert(varchar(20), timeBlock, 120), 12, 5),
        3, 1, '') as char(5)) as Military_Hour /* one of many options */

from
    (
    select dateadd(mi, (u8.n * 6 + u6.n) * 30, cast(@baseDate as datetime)) as timeBlock
    from
        (
            select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
            select 3      union all select 4 union all select 5
        ) as u6,
        (
            select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
            select 4      union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
        ) as u8
    ) as blocks
order by
    timeBlock
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131015/datetime-field-using-military-time-need-time-only-in-standard-time) might help you convert your datetimes to military time. You can then select just the time for `Military_Hour` and just the date for `Date`

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39251/sql-server-2008-group-by-30-minute-time-intervals) was used to find 30 minute intervals:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, yourDate) AS `Date`,
       CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, CONVERT(varchar(8),yourDate, 108) AS char(2)) + ':' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, CONVERT(varchar(8), yourDate, 108)/30 AS char(2)), as time) AS `Military_Hour`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CAST(yourDate AS date),DATEPART(MINUTE, yourDate)/30
```

You could also remove the concatenated colon if you wanted the `####` format instead of `##:##`