# SQL: Add space before AM/PM after military time conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I researched everywhere about this but I cannot seem to find it.

I have a column called OPEN_TIME which contains military time such as:

```
1900-01-01 23:00:00.000
```

I only want to extract the time, which I did successfully by doing:

```
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, OPEN_TIME, 100), 7))
```

However, this gives me a time of:

```
11:00PM
```

I would like to put a space before AM/PM so that it looks like:

```
11:00 PM
```

Not sure if this is as simple as it looks? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131015/datetime-field-using-military-time-need-time-only-in-standard-time ?

Comment: @Aron this one did not include a space

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sql server 2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 2012+ you can use Format()

```
Declare @Open_Time DateTime = '1900-01-01 23:00:00.000'
Select Format(@Open_Time,'hh:mm tt')
```

Returns

```
11:00 PM
```

I should note that Format() is not known for its performance.

Answer (score 1):

In any version of SQL Server you can use the `REPLACE` function

```
REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, OPEN_TIME, 100), 7)),'PM',' PM')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using 2012 or don't want to use Format you can accomplish this with STUFF.

```
Declare @Open_Time DateTime = '1900-01-01 23:00:00.000'
SELECT
    STUFF(
    LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @OPEN_TIME, 100), 7)),
    LEN(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @OPEN_TIME, 100), 7))) - 1,
    0,
    ' ')
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx